# symfony 1.4 propel:build-model not working as expected

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, yaml, propel

Just wondering if anyone might know what's happening here. I have several `schema.yml` files, and when I try to build model classes using `symfony propel:build-model` I don't get any error message, however instead of any classes being generated I get xml files generated in the same config folder as the schema yml files. i.e. if I have a file named `logger_schema.yml` in the config directory, after I run build-model, I will also have a `generated-logger_schema.xml` file in the config directory as well, and no generated classes.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Did you tried with only one `schema.yml` with only one table inside ?

Comment: Haven't tried that, I'm working with an existing project trying to add a single form to an already large project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML file in question is a worker file symfony/Propel creates as part of the class generation process - it's not an "error" as such.

symfony CLI tasks require quite a lot of PHP memory, especially on Windows. If the Propel task is failing, I would recommend a permanent change to the `php.ini` file setting on memory allocation to at least `256M`. I know this seems high, but you should only ever need these tasks on a development machine. As you note, you saw evidence of memory exhaustion on another related task.

If that doesn't fix it, could you add to your question all of the CLI output when you run the task? It might shed some light on the step which is failing.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this [ticket](http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/4217), it appears the XML files are likely the result of a symfony error, despite the fact that I repeatedly got no error message using `propel:build-model`. After trying `propel:build --model --forms`, I did in fact get a "memory exhausted" error, which was solved by temporarily increasing the PHP memory limit.